# Map object is copied during method call

Tags: c++, maps

For function:

```
void Function(int* integer, map<unsigned short, unsigned short> firstMap, map<int, unsigned char> secondMap);
```

Whenever I call it from another class like so...

```
Object->Function(integer, firstMap, secondMap);
```

A call is made to

```
std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,unsigned char,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,unsigned char> >,0> >::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,unsigned char,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<int const ,unsigned char> >,0> >
```

stepping into xtree the method being called is:

```
_Tree(const _Myt& _Right)
    : _Mybase(_Right.key_comp(), _Right.get_allocator())
    {   // construct tree by copying _Right
    _Init();
    _TRY_BEGIN
    _Copy(_Right);
    _CATCH_ALL
    _Tidy();
    _RERAISE;
    _CATCH_END
    }
```

What is this doing? Why is it being called? Are the maps being copied? Using very sleepy I was able to find that 20% of my cycle time is used up by this call.

Comment: Use a reference (`map<unsigned short, unsigned short>& firstMap`) if you don't want a copy, that simple.

Comment: And `const &` if you do not want to modify the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to pass the maps by reference rather than by value

```
void Function(int* integer, map<unsigned short, unsigned short>& firstMap, map<int, unsigned char>& secondMap);
```

Notice the addition of the '&'.

An additional feature of C++11 that you might be interested in is [moving in place](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) (if the variables are only used temporarily).